# Erro de conversão

Tags: java, sql, jtable

Estou tentando atualizar uma agenda através do JTable. Mas quando tento atualizar ele dá um erro

> java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for
>   cast

```
private class BtEditarListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int linhaSelecionada = -1;
            linhaSelecionada = tabela.getSelectedRow();
            if (linhaSelecionada >= 0) {
                int idContato = (Integer) tabela.getValueAt(linhaSelecionada, 0);
                AtualizarContato ic = new AtualizarContato(modelo, idContato, linhaSelecionada);
                ic.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "É necessário selecionar uma linha.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Como eu faço para conseguir realizar a conversam para atualizar.

O erro pode ser causado por conta do banco? Ou a versão do Java? O computador utiliza Acess e o Java está em 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Flávia Bruna, por favor poste o stack trace do erro. Da forma que você colocou parece ser aqui o erro:

```
int idContato = (Integer) tabela.getValueAt(linhaSelecionada, 0);
```

No entanto, aparentemente nada de anormal há aí já que o método retorna um Objetc e realmente precisa de um cast. Então, o ideial seria postar o stack trace.